# Rails 5: Server won't start because of old bundler bin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I recently upgraded to Rails 5 (recently like today) and since then every time I run a `rails s` I get this error:

```
    Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 5, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rails app:update:bin          # Use the new Rails 5 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:35:in `block in setup': You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 11.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from /Users/tfantina/Documents/Code and Websites/Ruby & Rails Stuff/prof-review/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:45:in `block in exec_app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:35:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:35:in `exec_app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

So as instructed I run `bundle config --delete bin` which seems to work although it doesn't return anything.  Then I move to the next step `rails app:update:bin` but I get the same error yet again:

```
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 5, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand...
```

So I feel like I've got some kind of endless look going here.

Comment: wild swing for the fences, but what happens when you run it as `bundle exec rails server` ?

Comment: What does `which rails` return when executed in the project root?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Jaydel that seems to have done the trick.  Although now after I bundle I get the message 
`Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor.` I'll have to look into this but I don't think it's a huge deal.

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved thus:
Go to the folder: yourapp / config / environments / development.rb, and add "#" in the last line "config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport :: EventedFileUpdateChecker".
Then on the console gave the following commands:
bundle config --delete bin # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
rails app:update:bin # Use the new Rails 5 executables
git add bin # Add bin/ to source control